# Add new text to already existing text in a content control, and make the already existing text in StrikeThrough

Tags: vba, ms-word, text-formatting, word-contentcontrol

I have a content control that already contains text. I want to add new text, and put the previous text in StrikeThrough, my code looks like this.

```
Sub testCCrangeModifier()
Dim CC As ContentControl
For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If CC.Title = "myContentControl" And CC.Tag = "myContentControl" Then
        CC.Range.Font.StrikeThrough = True
        CC.Range.Text = ("NEWTEXT" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & CC.Range.Text)
    End If
Next CC
End Sub
```

With this code, the result is:
 <s>NEWTEXT</s> 
 <s>OLDTEXT</s>

The result should look like this
**Before the macro:** 
OLDTEXT

**After the macro:**
NEWTEXT
 <s>OLDTEXT</s>

Chr(13) & Chr(10)  is the linebreak between the oldtext and newtext

Comment: Is it a Rich Text or Plain Text content control? Only Rich Text Content Controls can contain different formatting.

Comment: It's rich text. I have an idea, detect the length N of oldtext, and, put the last N characters in strikethrough, any idea of how to do that ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code sets the formatting before you add the text, so obviously
   any text that you add is going to have that formatting.
2. Only Rich Text Content Controls can contain different formatting.

The code below checks that `CC` is a rich text content control, then adds the text and removes strikethrough from the first paragraph.

```
Sub testCCrangeModifier()
   Dim CC As ContentControl
   For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
      If CC.Title = "myContentControl" And CC.Tag = "myContentControl" And CC.Type = wdContentControlRichText Then
         With CC.Range
            .Font.StrikeThrough = True
            .Text = ("NEWTEXT" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & CC.Range.Text)
            .Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.StrikeThrough = False
         End With
      End If
   Next CC
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works thanks, but only if i have 2 lines. I am writing this code to keep track of previous comments (oldtext), so it has to works for more than two lines. I have an idea, detect the length N of oldtext, and, put the last N characters in strikethrough, any idea of how to do that ? thanks

Comment: @gshep - Please see edited answer. When asking questions please ensure that you include all relevant information. Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For i = 2 To .Paragraphs.Count
                    .Paragraphs(i).Range.Font.StrikeThrough = True
I edited your code with this, it worked pefectly, thanks.

Comment: I guess your edit has better performance and it works as well